# What should dequeue return if the queue is empty

Tags: c++, queue

I am writing a queue in C++ (I'm not supposed to use the STL). My dequeue function needs to return the integer it removes from my queue. However, if the queue is empty what should it return?  Should I throw an exception and if so which one? Or should I return null (but couldn't that be confusing because that is essentially zero and make it look like I'm returning 0)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's up to you! You could make a contract with the user that dequeuing must only be done on a non-empty queue and wipe the hard disk if the queue is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Throwing an exception seems most appropriate, since the user should always either know that there is still an element in your queue or check it first by calling `.empty()` (assuming you do have such a method).

For the question of *what* exception you throw: [`std::logic_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) seems appropriate to me, use a "what"-string to point to your classes' name, the method called and that the queue was empty.

Comment: I think `std::runtime_error` is more appropriate for occasions where the error condition can't be predicted and avoided; if `.empty()` is a reliable way to avoid the error, `std::logic_error` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @DanielKO You are right, thanks. Fixed the answer and added some more hints as to what to put in the exception message.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options:

- Have a function [`boost::optional<T> pull()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/optional/doc/optional.html) which returns `boost::none` iff the queue is empty.
- Throw [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) or some similar exception.
- Document pulling from an empty queue as UB (you usually don’t want this).

I like the first option as it makes it explicit at the *type level* that a value can be not present, whilst the second and the third options are more at the *documentation/contract level*, which cannot be easily verified by the compiler.

Comment: It's usually called `pop`. :)

Comment: @avakar IME `pop`, `pull` and `dequeue` all occur. It’s a matter of style.

Comment: If boost is not an option, you can also use `std::pair<T, bool>` where the `.second` value of the pair dictates if the first is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The standard versions of `stack` and `queue` split the functionality of accessing the *next* elements and removing them:

```
stack<int> s;
// put some stuff in s
int i = s.top; // gets the top element
s.pop(); // removes the element you just retrieved in the previous operation
```

This allows `pop()` to be called on a empty container (and do nothing).  The `top` (or `front` and `back` function for a `queue`) rely on the underlying container (which you can specify) and which typically have undefined behavior if they are called on an empty container.

So, if you want to follow the standard's method for doing it, you can simply say that it is undefined to call it on an empty container.  If not, you can do whatever you want (give out your ex-girlfriend's phone number, perhaps?).